# How to deploy one web service and one internal service to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to deploy two services into one app to Heroku. So I created a new app in Heroku. I have dockerized my two Node.js services. Now I want to push both of them. I know in Heroku, there can only be one `web` process type.

So I pushed the "internal" service as process type `svc2`.

```
heroku container:push svc2 --app foo
```

And I pushed the web service as `web`.

```
heroku container:push web --app foo
```

The `web` service of course can be accessed from the web. But I cant access the `svc2` process type from within my web service.

In my webservice locally I used:

```
.get('http://0.0.0.0:3001/')
```

to access the "internal" service. I changed that to the Heroku URL now. But I don't know the port. How can I find out what the port of the `svc2` process type will be? I already configured

```
const port = process.env.PORT;
```

Do I really need to create a new app in Heroku to do that?
How can I let these 2 services communicate within one app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out what the port of the `svc2` process type will be?

It won't be accessible from the internet at all. [Only `web` dynos can receive traffic from the internet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations).

Beyond that, though, `0.0.0.0` isn't a real IP address. It's commonly used to mean "all IP addresses" when you're setting up a service, but you can't ever request anything from it.

If you are using the Common Runtime [you won't be able to communicate between dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-runtime#common-runtime):

> The Common Runtime provides strong isolation by firewalling all dynos off from one another. The only traffic that can reach a dyno is web requests forwarded from the router to web processes listening on the port number specified in the `$PORT` environment variable. Worker and one-off dynos cannot receive inbound requests.
>
> Individual processes within a dyno can bind to any address or port they want and communicate among them using e.g. standard TCP. The external networking interface (i.e.: eth0) for each dyno will be part of a /30 private subnet in the range 172.16.0.0/12, such as 172.16.83.252/30 or 172.30.239.96/30. Processes within one dyno don’t share IPs or subnets with other dynos, nor can they observe TCP session state of other dynos.

Note that your two process types will run on different dynos.

You [should be able to communicate between dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#private-spaces-runtime-networking) if you are using Private Spaces, but note that this is an [enterprise](https://www.heroku.com/enterprise) feature that likely costs quite a bit more:

> Dynos in a Private Space are all connected via a virtual private network configured as part of the space. Add-on data services installed in the space are also connected to this network. Similar to the Common Runtime, web processes can receive web requests by listening on the port number specified in the `$PORT` environment variable. In addition, any process in a dyno can choose to listen on a port number of choice and receive connections from other dynos on the private network. This is supported for web, worker and one-off processes.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for answering! Do you know if there is another way to let 2 services communicate with each other- other than using private spaces?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to run them as separate apps on Heroku.